# Why don't copy this dokument attributes from the source xml file?

Tags: xslt, attributes

i'm working the first time with xslt and i really don't understand why this xsl don't copy attributes from the source xml. Perhaps someone can give me a hint??

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:variable name="rpl" select="document('ParamInvoice.xml')"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:variable name="vInvoiceElement" select="$rpl/StoraInvoice/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:if test="$vInvoiceElement/Attribute">
            <xsl:call-template name="AttributeErzeugen">
               <xsl:with-param name="pAttr" select="$vInvoiceElement/Attribute"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="AttributeErzeugen">
      <xsl:param name="pAttr"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$pAttr">
         <xsl:attribute name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You need to provide the XML documents involved in the transformation -- otherwise people cannot be sure what the processing does.

Comment: You should also be clear about what you mean by attributes. The code actually copies elements from the external document as attributes with the same name to the elements in the current document. I do not see any errors here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<xsl:copy>`, you should use `<xsl:copy-of>`. The difference between both is that `copy` copies the element only (without attributes and child elements) and `copy-of` copies the entire elements (attributes, childs, etc).

Check http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_w3celementref.asp